# What's the point of the NOT operator?

Tags: c++

Currently checking out C++ using [this tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson2.html). It explains what the `! NOT` operator is, kind of, but I don't think I fully understand why I'd ever want to use it. Can someone please explain?

Comment: I would be very intrested in how you would then express `if(!x)` without it...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: `if(static_cast<bool>(x) == false)`, *obviously*.

Comment: obviously the fashionable thing to do is                       if(x)  {then do nothing}  else {do something}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, you want to divide the sum of two numbers to a third one, so you can do this if the third number is not zero.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
   {
    int a,b,c,sum;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    sum = a+b;
    if (c!=0) //which is equivalent to if(!c)
    cout << sum/c;
   }
```

I used an easy example in order to understand it quickly. Is everything okay now? Regards and good luck with your study.

Comment: I don't think this is a very good example. `!=` is of course not the same as `!`, and using `!` as a shorthand way of comparing to zero isn't ideal.

Comment: I know, but he just started learning C++ and I just wanted to give him a clue about this type of operator. When he will be 'a big boy' he will understand that I am a stupid newbie and my answer sucks. For now, it's good to keep it short and simple.

Answer (score 13):

The `!` operator is useful if you want to check that a condition is not currently satisfied.

Imagine a function that tells you if a particular subsystem of your application was initialized and another function to initialize it:

```
bool subsystem_is_initialized();
void subsystem_initialize();
```

You could check that it was initialized and initialize it if it wasn't using the not operator.

```
if (!subsystem_is_initialized())
    subsystem_initialize();
```

For all practical purposes, it's a shorter way to compare a value to zero, with an explicit suggestion that the affected value is boolean. You don't absolutely need it, but then again, neither do you need multiplications (you can loop over an addition), additions (you can do it with binary logic), or most of binary logic (you can do pretty much anything with NANDs, I've been told, but I haven't researched it myself).

Also keep in mind that, like almost all other C++ operators, it can be overloaded by classes.

Comment: Not to mention it's infinitely more readable than explicitly comparing to 0.

Comment: You can also "double-negate" to render something as a literal boolean. `!!` is a pattern often seen in dynamically typed languages where it first casts to `true` or `false`, then inverts. This is less common in C++ where `return foo` will automatically cast to the appropriate return type.

Answer (score 5):

A language is not always (in fact as good as never) defined to have the minimal set of features but a set of features that useful. For example, if you had the following code:

```
if (!test_something())
  do_something();
```

You could also express this as

```
if (test_something()) {
} else
  do_something();
```

but it would be less easy to read. So, while logical negation can usually be expressed by other constructs of the C++ language, it helps readability to express negation explicitly to indicate your intent.

Comment: An empty `if` clause is messy and should be avoided. It looks like you've intended to put something there and forgot to do it.

Comment: @tadman: Which is basically my point. It is legal but ugly, so it's a good thing you can use `!`.

Answer (score 5):

It's used when you need to flip a true/false in a condition, to increase readability.
e.g.
Compare

```
// Ensure that the thing is NOT red.
if (thing_is_red() == false)
    ...
if (!thing_is_red())
    ...
```

Comment: This is also a lot better than strictly asserting versus `NULL`, as in `if (pointer != NULL)` versus `if (pointer)` or `if (pointer == NULL)` as `if (!pointer)`.

Comment: @tadman That would depend on the coding style used. Personally, I only use `!` to flip conditions where I am comparing to true or false. I find that replacing explicit comparisons to NULL, or other data values requires too much knowledge of the particular quirks of whatever language you're using. True/false exist outside of computers, in traditional logic, which is stuff that *all* programmers need, regardless of programming language used.

Comment: If you don't know the "particular quirks" of C++, you should probably not be programming in C++ just as not knowing how to properly use a chainsaw means you should not be using one. Forgiving is not a term one would use to describe C++.

Answer (score 2):

`!` operator is used for negation purpose in bool condition checks. There are many places you can use it. Simple example:

```
 if (!existInArray(A, i))
```

check if `i` is NOT exist in array.

Answer (score 2):

`!` or the NOT operator is the logical equivalent of a `NOT` gate.

So, a `NOT` gate truth table says if `x` is true, then `!x` is false. and vice-versa.

Not too difficult if you think of it logically. For example NOT of male is a female, NOT true is false, NOT simple is complex..

Comment: Those are some pretty terrible examples. Gender is hardly a binary thing.

Comment: @tadman even transgenders would like to classify themselves in one or the other category. It was just an example :-)

Comment: "NOT" does not mean opposite.

Comment: @Pubby I am not sure I understand that in Boolean algebra :-)

Comment: What I mean to say is the analog world is rarely absolutes, that on a scale of 0.0 to 1.0 you rarely get the extremes. The binary world is *always* absolutes. Gender is one of those things that's usually one or the other, but often something else, like androgynous or deliberately unspecified.

Comment: @tadman I agree, the real world is analog. I have wondered about this a whole lot - that's why fuzzy logic is considered AI for it _tries_ to model the real world as accurately or inaccurately as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The [tutorial you mention](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson2.html):

> NOT: The NOT operator accepts one input. If that input is TRUE, it returns FALSE, and if that input is FALSE, it returns TRUE.

it means NOT operator is unary operator means single operand(not a binary operator)

like `&& and`||` are binary operators and there   syntax  is:

```
  result = operand1  && operand2
  result = operand1  || operand2
```

Unary is:

```
  result = !operand1
```

and its result values is revert of operand value id `operand1 = True` then result would be False and if `operand1 = False` result is True.

same is written there:

> For example, NOT (1) evaluates to 0, and NOT (0) evaluates to 1. NOT (any number but zero) evaluates to 0. In C and C++ NOT is written as !. NOT is evaluated prior to both AND and OR.

in c/c++ `0` is False and 
Non `0` is equivalent to True.

there is couple of good examples too!

(1).

```
!( 1 || 0 )
```

We know `1 || 0` is `1` means true and application of NOT operator makes it `0` means False:

```
    !( 1 || 0 )  
=>  ! (1)     
=>  0  that is false
```

Do you notice in this expression we have two operators  logical `||` or and `!` NOT operator.

```
    !( 1  || 0 )  
    ^      ^
    NOT   OR
```

and notice for OR operator `||` there is two operands bit single for unary NOT

Comment: *tutorial you are refereeing is good one*

Answer (score 2):

The most frequent case is probably with an `std::istream`:

```
int i;
std::cin >> i;
if ( ! std::cin ) {
    //  Something went wrong...
}
```

Other than that, all sorts of classes have `isValid()` or
`isDone()` functions; to iterate using a GoF iterator, for
example:

```
for ( IteratorType i( init ); ! i.isDone(); i.next() ) {
    //  Do something with i.element()
}
```

Map classes often have a `contains` function, so you might ask

```
if ( ! myMap.contains( key ) )
```

You'll also use boolean variables from time to time: for
a linear search where the match condition requires some
complicated evaluation, for example:

```
bool found = false;
int current = 0;
while ( ! found && current != end ) {
    //  maybe set found...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of the `!` operator is to make an expression that is `false` into a `true` expression. It is most often used as a replacement for `== false` or `== 0`. It often makes the expression easier to read:

if (p == NULL || p->next != NULL)

is the same as :

if (!p || p->next)

[Ok, so "easier to read" here is obviously quite subjective].

Comment: You got your checks wrong. It should be `p != NULL` if you want to avoid an illegal access on `p->next`.

Comment: No, I got the && instead of || wrong... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a number of answers explaining the NOT operator.

I am not a big fan of the `!` operator myself.  It is not nearly as visible as it should be (in that, it reverses the meaning of the clause).

For example, despite several years of programming in C++, it still takes me several seconds to parse `if ( ! ptr )` as opposed to `if ( ptr == NULL )` which instantly conveys me its meaning.

Does `if ( ! (i % 2) )` check for even or odd numbers?  If you didn't have the answer after your eyes went past the '?', and/or had to review the if condition again, you have just made my case.

Reviewing posts, I agree with some of the posters that the NOT operator has valid uses when applied to `bool`s and function calls.  Using `!` while processing streams is considered idiomatic.

That said, nearly every programmer I know has been bitten by `strcmp`.  I worked in a shop that has a few `#define`s such as `#define STRCMP_EQUAL 0` etc., and required the check to be written as `if ( STRCMP_EQUAL == strcmp(str1, str2) )` which, in my opinion, is orders of magnitude more explicit than `if ( ! strcmp(str1, str2) )`.

Answer (score 1):

! operator could be used with user defined datatypes(classes and structs in c++).
like every operator(expect . : and ::) !operator could be overloaded. See the following scenario.

```
//A is empty if memeber size is 0, and no further operations are allowed on other members if
// class is empty.
class A{
int size;
int lot;
int price;
public:
   bool operator!()
  {
      if(lot)
       return true; 
      else
      return false;
  }
};

A AObj;

//Aobj has size greater than 0
if(!Aobj)
{
//code to Fill or reuse the object.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of the ! operator is to make an expression that is false into a true expression. It is most often used as a replacement for == false or == 0. It often makes the expression easier to read:

if (p == NULL || p->next != NULL)

is the same as :

if (!p || p->next)

[Ok, so "easier to read" here is obviously quite subjective].